# Can anyone identify this logo?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, power-electronics

I am trying to repair an e-cigar. One of the ICs is cooked, it has 3 identical on board but I can not identify the company's logo to search for a replacement.

Been on the web for more than an hour already... I am out of ideas... 
This is the logo
[image]

and this is the whole IC
[image]

Any help will be deeply appreciated :)

Comment: Did you check [these manufacturers](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/other_manufacturer.html)?

Comment: That's a cool searcher @jippie

Comment: @jippie Searching by the information on the chip came with no useful results. :( Nice site though thank you!

Comment: It might help if you posted a less zoomed-in photo of the whole board, so we get some idea what these do.

Comment: How many pins do these have? Can't even tell that from your photo...

Comment: http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AON7534.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an AON7534 made by Alpha & Omega Semiconductor (AOSMD). The datasheet can be found [here](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AON7534.pdf).

This is a fairly bog standard N-Channel Trench MOSFET in a DFN package. Typically used for DC/DC converters etc. According to the datasheet it has a fairly high current rating with low \$R_{ds(on)}\$ (less than \$10\mathrm{m\Omega}\$).

---

And for completeness, this is the logo of the company from the datasheet in case anyone else ever find themselves searching for logos.

[image: AOSMD Logo]

Comment: Thank you Tom! I cant say that I have seen their logo before... Thanks again!

Comment: @Lamaseed I hadn't either, just typed in "datasheet 7534" into google, the third result was from "aosmd.com" which seemed promising as the logo was a A.

Comment: Seriously ?!?!? arg.... This happens to me often lately.....